# This simple polynomial plot looks working. Is really working?

Tags: python, linear-regression

I'm new to python and machine learning. So My question may be trivial.

I typed the below code in Jupyter Notebook

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X)
X_poly[:5]


lin_reg = LinearRegression()     
lin_reg.fit(X_poly, y)


plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.plot(X, lin_reg.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X)))
plt.show()
```

Then I deleted below code:

```
lin_reg = LinearRegression()      
lin_reg.fit(X_poly, y)
```

But a graph and regression are normally generated.

So those codes are not essential?

Chatgpt said that "without the training and fitting of the linear regression model, the predicted line would not be accurate and would not reflect the relationship between the input and target data."

But to me, the resultant graph and regression seems accurate ... even

```
lin_reg.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X[[2]]))
```

working

`lin_reg = LinearRegression()` `lin_reg.fit(X_poly, y)`

Are they meaningless?
Or Is something get wrong with deleting those codes?

ps. And please note to me if my question method is not right.

Comment: Please see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/3890632)

Answer (score 0):

Until you restart the runtime environment, your fitted model is still in the memory. You are addressing the model that was fit before you deleted the lines, so the will be no difference in the output. Once you restart the runtime environment, you will get a mistake "lin_reg not defined"